# Include node_modules while compiling SCSS in VS 2017

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2017

I have a project with style file in `wwwroot/css/site.scss`. I've installed *Web Compiler* extension to create css file. It works until I reference some module, eg. `@import "@material/button/mdc-button";` Error is *File to import not found or unreadable*.

Is it possible to include `wwwroot/node_modules/` to `compilerconfig.json`? Is there any other way to get the job done?

Answer (score 5):

After reading the source code for the Web Compiler and a little experimenting, I figured it out. Here is an example compilerconfig.json:

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "styles/app-styles.css",
    "inputFile": "styles/app-styles.scss",
    "options": {
      "includePath": "node_modules"
    }
  }
]
```